# double for loop in R with generated variables

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to calculate the distance from each of my 25000 observations to 50 US cities using their longitudes and latitudes. Ultimately I want to get the minimum distance of each observations to a major city, and identify that city.

My question in this loop is specifc to
**dist.{citygdpcoord$city[j]}** in the second loop, how do I make it point to the dataframes that were generated by the first loop?

```
for(j in 1:50)
{
  assign(paste("dist",citygdpcoord$city[j],sep="."), 0)

for(i in 1:25509) 
{
  haver <- sin((citygdpcoord$latitude[j]-geofinlit$latitude[i])/2)*
          sin((citygdpcoord$latitude[j]-geofinlit$latitude[i])/2)+
          cos(geofinlit$latitude[i])*cos(citygdpcoord$latitude[j])*
          sin(citygdpcoord$longitude[j]-geofinlit$longitude[i])*sin(citygdpcoord$longitude[j]-geofinlit$longitude[i])
  dist.{citygdpcoord$city[j]}<- data.frame(6371.393*2*atan2(sqrt(haver),sqrt(1-haver)))

}
}
```

Comment: maybe you could explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Why are there brackets around `citygdpcoord$city[j]` in the last line? I've never seen that before, so pardon my ignorance if that's real syntax, but it looks like improper syntax to me.

Comment: I think you want the `get()` function. Such as `get(paste('dist',citygdpcoord$city[j],sep="."))`

Comment: Hi I'm trying to make the dataframe in the second loop point to the variable generated in the first loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your biggest problem is going to be that `dist.{citygdpcord$city[j]}` is going to be overwritten 25509 times and only the last value will be saved. I'd recommend changing a couple of things. First, use matrices and convert them to a dataset at the end. This way you can preallocate the object size and not grow it as you loop. Also, store your data frames in a list so you only have one object and not 50. Maybe something like this?

```
dat <- lapply(1:50, function(j) { 
  tmp <- matrix(0, nrow = 25509, ncol = 1) 
  for (i in 1:25509) { 
    haver <- ... # removed code for simplicity
    tmp[i, ] <- c(6371.393*2*atan2(sqrt(haver), sqrt(1-haver)))
  }
  return(as.data.frame(tmp)) 
})
```

Then name your list like `names(dat) <- paste("dist",citygdpcoord$city[1:50], sep = ".")`

I'm not sure if this gets at what you're trying to accomplish, but hopefully it does.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I want.